# Get if a date is older than one day using Carbon

Tags: php, php-carbon

I would like to know if a date is older than 1 day using Carbon. 
I have tried:

```
$date = Carbon::parse($loggedUser->exchange_keys_last_time);
$now = Carbon::now();
var_dump($date);
var_dump($now);
dd($date->diffInDays($now));
```

`$loggedUser->exchange_keys_last_time = 2018-04-04 00:00:00.000000` and `$now = 2018-04-02 15:16:18.902924` and I'm getting this weird result saying that the `diffInDays() = 1` which in my mind doesn't make sense since these dates are two days apart.

Any suggestion to get if `$date` is older than 1 day comparing to `$now`?

Comment: Why do you think it's weird? The diff is 1 full day and around 9 hours of another. Since the diff must be an integer, it simply gets rounded down to 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not concerned about anything smaller than a second (it seems you're not), you can simply compare the difference in seconds against a known value (seconds in a day).

```
$secondsInDay = 86400; // 3600 * 24

$expired = $date->diffInSeconds($now) > $secondsInDay;
```

Do note that this probably won't work with DST change and you should look into other solutions if that's a concern for you.